# How to hide php echo in a dropdown menu?

Tags: php, html-select

I have a drop down box that shows the weight of the item and how much extra the heavier items cost. I also have javascript that updates the price on the page based on the value selected in the dropdown. Since the javascript updates the price shown on the page, I would like to remove the additional price shown next to the option choices.

the code is:

```
<?php if ($options) { ?>
    <?php foreach ($options as $option) { ?>
    <?php if ($option['type'] == 'select') { ?>
    <span id="option-<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>" class="option">
      <select name="option[<?php echo $option['product_option_id']; ?>]">
        <?php foreach ($option['option_value'] as $option_value) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $option_value['product_option_value_id']; ?>"><?php echo $option_value['name']; ?>
        <?php if ($option_value['price']) { ?>
        (<?php echo $option_value['price_prefix']; ?><span id="newPrice"><?php echo $option_value['price']; ?></span>)
        <?php } ?>
        </option>
        <?php } ?>
      </select>
    </span>
```

I only want to show the product_option_id in the drop down, I don't want to show the added price for increases; I don't want this part of the code to be visable:

```
<?php if ($option_value['price']) { ?>
        (<?php echo $option_value['price_prefix']; ?><span id="newPrice"><?php echo $option_value['price']; ?></span>)
        <?php } ?>
```

however, I have some javascript that updates price based off the $option_value['price']. So I can't just erase it.

Is there a way to keep the output from echoing onto the screen, but still have javascript be able to find it?

Comment: You could add the value directly in javascript from the start (using PHP); and let it control what is shown in the drop down.

Comment: Off to look for some tutorials on that. post some up if you know any too, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes:

```
<?php if ($option_value['price']) { ?>
        (<?php echo $option_value['price_prefix']; ?><span style="display:none" id="newPrice"><?php echo $option_value['price']; ?></span>)
        <?php } ?>
```

Also you should consider not using an ID on that span, unless you are generating a unique id for each one, as it will cause you problems when you try to grab it with document.getElementById()

Comment: I thought so too... but for some reason the style is not working. seems strange as I use display:none in some other areas too...

Comment: Still haven't got it yet. As for the display:none --> You can't style <option> with css seems to be the consensus. Thanks though.